# How to Find Which Ocean a Coordinate is on

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, google-maps, mapkit

I have some coordinates, which will always be somewhere in an ocean. I need a way to convert the coordinates into a string telling which ocean/sea the coordinate falls. Is there any convenient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using MapKit, you can use the `CLGeocoder` method `– reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:` to perform a reverse geocoding request. The completion handler returns an array of `CLPlacemark` objects. If you take a look at the [CLPlacemark Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLPlacemark), you'll see that there is an `ocean` property that contains the name of the ocean associated with the placemark. I'm assuming this will also apply to seas; if not, try the `inlandWater` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse